# Native dom event persistance regarding event bubbling

Tags: javascript

I don't know why I've never thought about this before, but what is the lifetime of native dom events. Are they reused and how so, do they expire? Is there a way to kind of freeze them like React synthetic events? **To be more specific I mean as they bubble up through the dom**

Simple Test:

```html
<div onclick="setTimeout(() => { console.log(event.currentTarget)}, 0)">Test 1</div>
</div>


<div onclick="console.log(event.currentTarget)">Test 2</div>
</div>
```

Running "Test 1" compared to test "Test 2" shows that the current target is null. This is just one example to exemplify the larger question I have.

Ty!

Edit: Here's a code pen to test with https://codepen.io/rubixibuc/pen/qBbwRmo?editors=1111

Comment: No DOM event don't get reused. Its a new event each time.

Comment: I mean as the work their way up the dom tree

Comment: if you are talking about event bubbling which bubbles way up the dom tree, then yes it's the same eventobject.

Comment: Have put that, please accept it if you find appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - DOM events don't get reused. Its a new event each time.if you are talking about event bubbling which bubbles way up the DOM tree, then yes it's the same event Object.